# How to delete bulk rows in Ignite's SQL table

Tags: sql, caching, ignite, gridgain

Can someone please suggest me an efficient way to bulk delete rows from a table using SQL query?

Comment: It shouldn't be this - In a loop to execute SqlFieldsQuery query = new SqlFieldsQuery("DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE URL = '"+key+"'");
cache.query(query);

Comment: Please avoid concatenating strings to your SQL statements, as this leads to vulnerability.

Comment: Yeah.. sure.. we will use prepared statement.. It's just an example..

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `cache.removeAll(keys)` from Cache API? Sometimes SQL is not the most straightforward way.

Comment: removeAll? How can I do it for table data? As URL is only one of the columns of that table I mentioned

Comment: Each Ignite table is also a cache, from which you can remove entries by key. You can try iterating them with `ignite.cacheNames()`.

Comment: In removeAll(keys).. How can you say URL as a key.. In a table, more than two columns can exist, right? In that case, which column goes in removeAll argument? These are columns -> ID, URL, SCORE, APPNAME. Here Index exists on ID (primary key) and APPNAME (varchar). I'll have only URLs beforehand.

Comment: Primary keys should be passed to removeAll.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response.. But I won't be having primary key values beforehand.

Comment: When would you have them then? There do they come from?

Comment: I have a table with columns ID, URL, SCORE, APPNAME. Usually when we get data we'll create autoIncrement sequence id and add a row in the table with some URL, SCORE, APPNAME. Usually in the application, there are 3 functionalities GET, ADD and CHECK. CHECK - We'll get outgoing URLs from some website pages. We need to check if those URLs are present in the given table. There is relation between URL and SCORE. ADD - Add unique URLS into the table with score for each URL. GET - Get top 10 URLs sorted in ascending order of SCORE. Now we are getting bad performance for CHECK function.

Comment: If I create an extra cache for the table data (as redundant data) with APPNAME+URL as key and ID as value.. I think I can achieve good performance.. I will check and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: I still don't understand where is removing in your workflow.

Comment: It's actually one of the functions in CHECK. Sorry, please forget about the case. I was just in a dilemma whether to delete unindexed column data using where clause in SQL or whether to just create another K-V cache for that column data alone in order to get PKIDs of that table as it's giving slow performance.